# Response to class

Tags: json, string, response

i have http get request like

```
{"meta":{"code":200,"requestId":"595cc7784c1f67701d721227"},"response":{"venues":[{"id":"5564370c498e52484ec3249f","name":"Aras Döner & Kokoreç","contact":{},"location":{"lat":41.187417726573926,"lng":27.76829713785891,"labeledLatLngs":[{"label":"display","lat":41.187417726573926,"lng":27.76829713785891}],"distance":12,"cc":"TR","country":"Türkiye","formattedAddress":["Türkiye"]},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d16e941735","name":"Fast Food Restoranı","pluralName":"Fast Food Restoranları","shortName":"Fast Food","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/fastfood_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":2038,"usersCount":740,"tipCount":0},"allowMenuUrlEdit":true,"beenHere":{"lastCheckinExpiredAt":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"summary":"Burada kimse yok","groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1499252600","venueChains":[],"hasPerk":false}],"confident":false}}
```

How can i print specific attribute like "venues" name=...

Answer (score 0):

you can print the value in the console using console.log()

For example, to print the names of all venues in the response...

```
var r = {"meta":{"code":200,"requestId":"595cc7784c1f67701d721227"},"response":{"venues":[{"id":"5564370c498e52484ec3249f","name":"Aras Döner & Kokoreç","contact":{},"location":{"lat":41.187417726573926,"lng":27.76829713785891,"labeledLatLngs":[{"label":"display","lat":41.187417726573926,"lng":27.76829713785891}],"distance":12,"cc":"TR","country":"Türkiye","formattedAddress":["Türkiye"]},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d16e941735","name":"Fast Food Restoranı","pluralName":"Fast Food Restoranları","shortName":"Fast Food","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/fastfood_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":2038,"usersCount":740,"tipCount":0},"allowMenuUrlEdit":true,"beenHere":{"lastCheckinExpiredAt":0},"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"summary":"Burada kimse yok","groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1499252600","venueChains":[],"hasPerk":false}],"confident":false}};
var venues = r.response.venues;
for (i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) { 
    console.log(venues[i].name)
}
```